# Android EditText content multiplies when orientation changed

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have weird situation with EditText.
Situation:

1. set device to landscape mode
2. enter text to EditText and press
   "DONE"
3. change orientation
4. EditText contains doubled text that
   was typed

the code:

```
private EditText enterText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    enterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterText);
}
```

If I comment the line with findViewById, everything is working properly.

Any ideas why this happens?

EDIT: I've double checked and it happens every time, not only if the line I was written about is commented.. :-\

EDIT2: It happens only on first orientation change event. Every next is OK..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you rotate your phone the Activity restarts, which probably calls something that causes your text to be written again somehow. This is part of the OS and a bit annoying, here is that to do.

If you in your manifest add:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

to the activity node in which the rotation is done, you'll have to override the *onConfigurationChanged*.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);

}
```

Whenever your phone rotates the overriden method will call and you can do a special initialization like ignore the input if there was an input earlier and such. Hope this gets you on the right track!

PS: You can also pipeline the *configChanges* with different other "values/configs". Such as *keyboardHidden* and many others.

They are listed on the **[following link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear)**